# Guidewire ClaimCenter Policy Level Coverages

Tags: guidewire

During FNOL, I am unable to see automated exposure creation and policy level coverages into my local but it's working in higher environments. I have imported exposure rules into my local environment but still issue persists. Not getting any error but need to see automated exposure creations and policy level coverages into my local. Do we need to do any mapping in local env? Please suggest.

NOTE: Automated exposure creates through exposure rules (under Administration -> Business Settings -> Exposure Rules). I have already checked the trigger conditions and it's satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

We need to import coveragecode.xml and exposure rules into local and it is working.